# How avoid the click transfer between brother views?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have three layout layers and over the blue one, two views (EditText and a simply view), so let's put some context:

- When I set on click listener only to yellow layer and touch inside the blue one for example, the click is listened only in the yellow layer, the click is transfer. [ClickTransferBetweenChilds](https://gfycat.com/harmlessgrayhoneycreeper)
- When I set on Click listener in all layers the click listener is triggered when I touch anywhere inside each layer. [ClickNotTransferWhenSetClickListener](https://gfycat.com/accomplishedorderlyladybug)
  This is the default android behavior and I call this layer stack, parent-child views, there's the following schema:

Yellow - is parent of -> Red - is parent of -> Blue.

Now focus on the blue layer, over the blue layer are super posed two elements, the EditText and the View, the EditText is over the View, and initially with the default android behavior when I touch the upper left side, the keyboard is called (because the EditText is below) but I want to avoid this behavior. Please call it brother propagation.

I make a simply solution please refer to line 71 [Gist](https://gist.github.com/AndresMaca/5d44610b4576984e38b8ef5e443c8a54) in MainActivity.java, but we can't implement in production because I can only touch the Layout things (the yellow one - Parent - at possible).

TL/DR: I want to avoid this behavior [ClickTransferBetweenBrothers](https://gfycat.com/solidunrealisticimperialeagle) how to avoid transfer click between brothers **keeping** the click transfer between parent-child views.

Comment: Is View over the EditText?

Comment: Yes! @JuanSancho you can see the appended gifs or ask me, thank for the answer.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but shall the answer be as simple as make the View clickable?

Comment: @JuanSancho Yes that will be an option, but I Can't do that, that's will be a 'dirty' solution and we can't not attach unused listener, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: I mean, if you make the View "clickable", it will avoid EditText clicks on the View's area, and it's not neccessary to set any "empty" listener to the View, because it will do nothing by default, which is what you want, isn't it?
So check the "clickable" option on View, and don't set any listener, and see what happens